# How to fix kivy is not a package error in command line?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy and I recently downloaded it to make apps. But whenever I type the following code in my text editor:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kiv.uix.label import Label
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Heyo")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named "kivy.app"; kivy is not a package
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: execute: `python -m pip install kivy`

Comment: did you create file `kivy.py` or folder `kivy` ? Rename it.

Comment: Wow, this was really helpful, that's what the problem was, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your 'kivy' installation is in venv or outside of where you're trying to call it. Unless you haven't installed it as previously mentioned.

Comment: I've already tried to install the package and the same error shows, is there any way I can uninstall the app and re-download the pip file again?

Comment: Yes, `pip uninstall <module>` or `python -m pip uninstall <module>` 

This all depends where your installation is sitting and which python you're trying to call it from. 

What ide are you using?